# Error with copy/paste in excel 2010 VBA when trying to insert charts, ranges etc into word

Tags: vba, excel

In researching this error I've come to the conclusion that it has to do with the clipboard not clearing like it should which wasn't an issue when we were using 2003 but is now that we are using 2010.  (I also inherited this code from someone who doesn't work here anymore)

> Run-Time error "4605":
>       This method or property is not available because the clipboard is empty or not valid.

This is my code:

```
Worksheets("Exec Sum").Range("B140:I186").Copy

With myDoc.Bookmarks
  .Item("b3").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=bmark, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

' Clears Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I've tried sendkeys ("^C")  with selecting an empty cell first but no luck.  Is there any way that I could either not use the copy/paste method to do this or a different way to clear the clipboard?

Comment: Which line is failing? The `.Copy` or the `.PasteSpecial`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I started getting this error when I upgraded from 2003 to 2010, but the macro still worked in 2003.

The tables were there, but I noticed that sometimes the copying didn't work. As this didn't ever happen in debug mode, I added 5 secs waiting time right before the copying.

This makes the macro slower, but at least it works.

Comment: Sorry I got side tracked at work for another task and couldn't come back to this for a little while.  Anyway thanks for this it allowed me to have the code work in 2010.

Comment: How to make those delays?!

Comment: Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:01#) -- See the wait method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 7):

I'm still testing my solution but it's different than the suggestions made and so far has worked flawlessly.  Just a different approach:

I add a label and surround my attempt to copy with an error handler...

```
Pg1CopyAttempt:
    DoEvents
    shSomeSheet.Range("A1:G30").Copy
    On Error GoTo Pg1PasteFail
    WordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    On Error goto 0 'disable the error handler
```

I call the label "Pg1CopyAttempt" because I know that Excel, through no fault of my own, may fail to copy it to the clipboard.  If Excel does let me down, I won't know until I try to paste.  When I do try I get thrown to the error Handler (Pg1PasteFail) when the paste method fails.  This sits at the bottom of my routine (after a straight exit sub or an exit routine).

```
Pg1PasteFail:
If Err.Number = 4605 Then ' clipboard is empty or not valid.
    DoEvents
    Resume Pg1CopyAttempt
 End If
```

It would be better to test for an empty clipboard programatically than to rely on an error handler but the idea here is to force a loop so that it keeps trying to copy until it succeeds.  The simpler loop with programatic testing of the clipboard could exploit Sean's ClipboardEmpty Function (above).  DoEvents is still exploited but even with DoEvents the routines can fail and are just instructed to keep trying.

Comment: So I managed to implement this in a slightly different form since my code copies on one line of code and pastes on a different line.  This definitely is not the most elegant way but it works(so far).  I numbered the lines of my code and used a select case function with 'erl' in the error section.  In order to step back one line I used the 'goto' cmd (i know) to the line of code that copies.

Comment: You saved me man!  I see this is old but I wanted to let you know that it's 12:45 a.m. and I can go to bed now thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use:

```
Private Declare Function apiOpenClipboard Lib "user32" Alias "OpenClipboard" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function apiEmptyClipboard Lib "user32" Alias "EmptyClipboard" () As Long
Private Declare Function apiCloseClipboard Lib "user32" Alias "CloseClipboard" () As Long
Private Declare Function CountClipboardFormats Lib "user32" () As Long

Function ClipboardEmpty() As Boolean
    ClipboardEmpty = (CountClipboardFormats() = 0)
End Function

Sub EmptyClipboard()
  If apiOpenClipboard(0&) <> 0 Then
    Call apiEmptyClipboard
    Call apiCloseClipboard
  End If
End Sub
```

the function `ClipboardEmpty` is a test. e.g. `if clipboardempty then`
The sub `EmptyClipboard` will simply clear the clipboard

Comment: Sorry got side tracked at work and couldn't comeback to this for a little bit. Thanks a lot for the solution although this didn't solve it for 100% of the time.  The other person saying to delay the code a few seconds after each copy made it so it was a 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't confirmed this as a final solution, but the hang up seems to be when copying - The copied data never makes it onto the clipboard, so the code fails when attempting to paste.  Clearing the clipboard of any previously copied data before initiating the next copy command seemed to help.  I still am using the wait time shown above, but I seem to be able to get away with a shorter wait time using the following function to clear the clipboard:

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: I had a similar issue. Clearing the clipboard between copying arrays has done the trick.